# Sample code on Restoring transaction is unclear

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

```
NSMutableArray *productIDsToRestore = <# From the user #>;
SKPaymentTransaction *transaction = <# Current transaction #>;

if ([productIDsToRestore containsObject:transaction.transactionIdentifier]) {
    // Re-download the Apple-hosted content, then finish the transaction
    // and remove the product identifier from the array of product IDs.
} else {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
}
```

Above reference code is from StoreKit guide, Restoring Completed Transactions chapter. What I can't understand here why `productIDsToRestore` is searched for transaction ID? What is the object inside it? If it's object keyed with transaction ID, then as Apple stated earlier in chapter, transaction ID is unique each time. Only original transaction ID will be the same.

Comment: Can you link to the code you are reading ?

Comment: There is no more than that. It is from Apple IAP [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html).

Comment: Read the paragraph immediately above the code : If your app uses the app receipt and has Apple-hosted content, let the user select which products to restore before starting the restoration process. During restoration, re-download the user-selected content and finish any other transactions immediately.

Comment: So how does it answer my question?

Comment: I'll read through and see if I can work it out.